# How to retrieve existing jquery datatable(initialized on document on ready) onclicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatable

I have successfully initialized a jquery datatable on document ready with server side processing. Now I need to display same datatable on clicking a checkbox. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    var oTable = $('#example1').dataTable({
            //"bAutoWidth":true,
            "bDestroy":true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/alldata/",

         });
```

Now when I click on a checkbox, I need to display same table.

```
$("#allid").click(function()
{ 
    if ($('#allid').is(':checked')){
        oTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
        oTable.fnDraw();
   }
});
```

I have tried the above way but it is not working, Please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Is this checkbox on the same page?

Comment: @auL5agoi, Yes, that checkbox is on the same page placed above the table

Comment: Are you getting any js errors in Firebug console?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(function () {                     
    var trigger $("#allid");
    trigger.on("click", function() {
        if ($('#allid').is(':checked')) {
            oTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
            oTable.fnDraw();
            console.log("should display the table now");
        } else {
            console.log("some error");
        }   
    }); 
});
```

**If this is not working try it with a try catch block like so:**

```
$(function () {
    try {
        var trigger $("#allid");
        trigger.on("click", function() {
            if ($('#allid').is(':checked')) {
                oTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
                oTable.fnDraw();
                console.log("should display the table now");
            }
       });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }   
});
```

Open up your developer console and wait for any messages while refreshing the page. 
Paste the error.